# Is it true that Manchester airport had no arrivals or departures the morning of Sept 2nd 2017?

Tags: air-travel, weather-and-climate, man

For Tuesday 2nd September 2017, between 05.45 am - 12.45 pm at Manchester, the airline says no flights were made either incoming or outgoing due to weather conditions. Is this true?

Comment: Have you seen this https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=9Q0lu6OqlSo ?